# Wildfly 10 - How to use a newer version of jackson for an aplication

Tags: jackson, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have an application running on wildfly 10 that needs a newer version of jackson. Simply updating the maven dependency does not to work. Wildflys own version seems to interfere...

Somebody has a hint?

Comment: Why did you vote down my question ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a newer version of Jackson to your war and use that, but the JAX-RS subsystem of the container (Resteasy) will still use it's own jackson module to (de)serialize you HTTP request/response bodies.

You could add a module with the newer version, but you could run into dependency problems with other modules (see [this pull request](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/8519) which already was accepted, so it should be in the next release, but I don't know of any planned Wildfly release dates).

Or you could package your own version of Jackson and register those MessageBodyReaders/Writers to be used by JAX-RS. This should do the job.

```
@Provider
public class CustomJacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {}
```

You may also have to exclude the built-in Jackson by adding a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```